# Firebase Analytics User time for performing actions

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I would like to measure how long (on average) users are performing certain actions in my app. For example, the time it takes for a user to add an item to the cart till the time to purchase the items. Can Firebase analytics track these time differences? If so, how can I get a report out of it or add it to my dashboard.

I know this can be done using traces in Performance monitoring, but I want to know these time differences not to troubleshoot performance issues but rather behavioral issues for my users.